# QGIS slope output problems

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, slope, usgs

I've been trying to calculate slope in percentage for a project I'm working on but keep running into this issue

1. Whenever I calculate slope using the designated Slope tool or the r.slope.aspect tool I get these lines all over my output (see below). This happens when I try to calculate either percentage or degrees. I have seen similar problems to this on StackExchange and they all suggested mosaicking the raster using a bilinear interpolation. The image below is the output after doing that, so it doesn't seem to have worked.  [image]

Extra information: I'm using the USGS 3DEP raster images for California. I mosaicked three images using build vrt with bilinear interpolation. I then reprojected the images to EPSG:26910 (units are in meters).

Answer (score 7):

The herringbone pattern in your image is a classic indication that a *Nearest Neighbor* resampling occurred somewhere in your workflow. I suggest that you go back through each processing step and closely review each tool's *Resampling* options and make sure that you select either *Bilinear* or *Cubic*.

For example, you mention that you conducted a reprojection, but you did not state if you selected the *Reproject* tool's appropriate resampling option.  I suspect that you allowed *Reproject* to operate with the default *Nearest Neighbor* setting, which may be the source of your problem.

Finally, when symbolizing your raster data, you must also select *Bilinear* or *Cubic* resampling within *Layer Styling > Resampling*.